# How to avoid the 0-byte file on Webclient download error

Tags: c#, .net, http, download, webclient

When using the following code to download a file:

```
WebClient wc = new WebClient();
wc.DownloadFileCompleted += new System.ComponentModel.AsyncCompletedEventHandler(wc_DownloadFileCompleted);
wc.DownloadFileAsync("http://path/file, "localpath/file");
```

and an error occurs during the download (no internet connection, file not found, etc.)
it allocates a 0-byte file in localpath/file which can get quite annoying.

is there a way to avoid that in a clean way?

(i already just probe for 0 byte files on a download error and delete it, but i dont think that is the recommended solution)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you reverse engineer the code for `WebClient.DownloadFile` you will see that the `FileStream` is instantiated before the download even begins. This is why the file will be created even if the download fails. There's no way to ammend that code so you should cosnider a different approach.

There are many ways to approach this problem. Consider using `WebClient.DownloadData` rather than `WebClient.DownloadFile` and only creating or writing to a file when the download is complete and you are sure you have the data you want.

```
WebClient client = new WebClient();

client.DownloadDataCompleted += (sender, eventArgs) =>
{
    byte[] fileData = eventArgs.Result;
    //did you receive the data successfully? Place your own condition here. 
    using (FileStream fileStream = new FileStream("C:\\Users\\Alex\\Desktop\\Data.rar", FileMode.Create))
        fileStream.Write(fileData, 0, fileData.Length);
};

client.DownloadDataAsync(address);
client.Dispose();
```

Comment: ok, i dont like this solution 100% because i have to take care of the writing myself, but it is still better than my current approach. btw, how do you reverse engineer compiled .net code?